# Spring Boot: Properties in Parent/Child Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, parent-child, properties-file

So, Spring Boot automatically loads the application.properties and makes the properties available for it´s ApplicationContext, so that i.e. XML-Bean-Definitions can use them.
But i can´t find a way to "expose" these properties to Child-Contexts. I have to define a Bean for a PropertyPlaceholder in each Childcontext to manually load the application.properties from the classpath.

Is there a way to give the properties to the ChildContext, so that they are automatically resolved when used? I don´t want to load the .properties-File in the Child-Context.

Basically i create the parent-Child-Relationship with

```
new  SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).child(BaseApplication.class).run();
```

If i have a application.properties (defined in the Application-Module) with a property called username=XXX, i can access this property of course inside the Application-Module.
But, if i have a Beandefinition inside the Child-Context (BaseApplication), let´s say:

```
<bean id="beanB" class="com.example.nsm.BeanB" >
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${username}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${password}"/>
</bean>
```

the properties are not resolved. I have to manually load the application.properties from the classpath with

```
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then they are resolved.

In fact, i do not want to load the properties like this.
Beandefinitions from parent are visible for the Child, but properties are not? Why not? Is this intentional? If not, can this be fixed?

Comment: How do you create the child context ? Show us some relevant code / config.